# Clear .net apps' (asp and desktop app) cache from asp application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wpf, caching

in my company, we use 1 database for all of our applications. We have one ASP.Net website and several desktop apps (WPF, WinForms).

Each application has its own cache system. For example, ASP.Net website uses IIS caching and desktop apps use memory caching.

We developped an admin website (ASP.Net MVC 5) to manage global configuration. When we update data in our database from this website, we would like to tell the others apps to update their cache.

What would be the best solution to do that ?

[image: What we want !]

Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, the easiest way is to poll the database every X seconds to ask whether the cache should be reloaded. This can be done by remembering the previous state (an integer for example). If it deviates, reload the cache.

You can also let the database send a change notification on a table change, which will have a better performance than polling every time.

The last option is to use a common source for the memory cache, which is shared across all systems. Then you don't need to keep them in sync at all.

Comment: Hi !

First, thanx for your hep ! The third solution, wich seems to be the best, is impossible now because we would have to make deep changes in some of our bigest applications architectures.

For the second solution, how would you send this notification ? With wich tech ?

Comment: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx) for SQL Server for example. Similar solutions are there for other platforms.

Comment: I read your link but I think is not adapted to our applications. Indeed, we have objects in our cache which depend of multiple tables. So, we want to find a way to say "Reload users cache", even if User object is based on 10 tables.

Comment: You can store that ID somewhere in a global table. If you clear the cache, update a line in that table.